Temperature dependent Structural and electronic Properties in Quantum espresso
I want to calculate temperature properties of hexagonal materials. Specifically, I want to know how lattice parameters, bond lengths and atomic positions changes. Further I want to compute thermal excitations and temperature dependent band structures etc.
I only have Quantum espresso. How to calculate above properties using it?

For lattice parameters etc, you have to use AIMD. In quantum espresso, you can use CPMD/MD to do that. For temperature dependent properties, you can follow EPW package of quantum espresso.

can you please provide detailed elaboration?   As I'm not aware of the software you mentioned. Thanks for your comment.

Also can you provide an example calculation of temperature dependence of lattice parameters using EPW?

You can follow the following links:
https://docs.epw-code.org/doc/Contact.html
https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/user_guide_PDF/cp_user_guide.pdf

@MuhammadHasan why not write an answer?

For lattice parameters, bond lengths and atomic positions changes, you should use Ab initio molecular dynamics (AIMD). In quantum espresso, you can use CPMD/MD to do that (https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_CP.html).
For temperature dependent band structures, you can follow EPW package of quantum espresso.
You can follow the following links:
(http://docs.epw-code.org/doc/Contact.html)
They have shown how to calculate temperature dependent properties using Quantum Espresso and those are very user friendly tutorials.
